# vue router history mode page reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

how can i achieve that the same breakpoints are hit (the same functions are called) in hash mode and history mode?

when i read https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

> we can use the router's history mode, which leverages the history.pushState API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload

i assumed that my page won't be reloaded when the URL changes no matter what mode the router is in - in hash mode and in history mode - basically that my page will behave the same

my page opens like this:

```
www.example.com
```

when i type a new URL in browser and press Enter (i want to use the new URL as a search query)

in hash mode:

```
www.example.com/#/action comedy 1080p 2017
```

only breakpoint1 and breakpoint2 are hit and string `newVal == "action comedy 1080p 2017"` - it works as expected

but in history mode:

```
www.example.com/action comedy 1080p 2017
```

breakpoint1 and breakpoint2 are NOT hit, but breakpoint3, breakpoint4, breakpoint5, breakpoint6 are hit - and my page doesn't function as it should

can i achieve the same functionality in both modes and how?

thank you!

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  //mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/:question' }
  ]
})

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    watch:{
      '$route.params': function (newVal, oldVal){
        alert("breakpoint1");
      },
      '$route.params.question': function(newVal, oldVal){
        alert("breakpoint2");
      }
    },
    beforeCreate(){
      alert("breakpoint3");
    },
    created(){
      alert("breakpoint4");
    },
    beforeMount(){
      alert("breakpoint5");
    },
    mounted(){
      alert("breakpoint6");
    },
    beforeUpdate(){
      alert("breakpoint7");
    },
    updated(){
      alert("breakpoint8");
    }
  });
```

Comment: when it's not hashed, and you hit enter in browser, it definitely going to reload. That's the browser. Nothing you can do to change it with javascript

Comment: just curious. why do u need this function anyway ?

Comment: @JacobGoh i would like that URL functions as search - you can search the contents of my page by typing the search query after the root www.example.com/ and the result can be bookmarked

Comment: may i know why would hash mode not works in this case ?

Comment: @JacobGoh hash mode works perfectly - i just want to get rid of the ugly /#/ if that is possible

Comment: oh, understood. Hash mode and history mode will definitely work differently. I think you can stop bothering about making them works in the same way